# xml box layout or other suggestions

Tags: android, xml

I am programming an android app for making work-fiches, main screen needs to show some summary of:working hours, parts used, remarks, ... , how can i design in xml these boxes the best way? I need a title, an summary content, clickable,...
The android design guidelines doesn't give me immediately a solution for it, also it is very difficult to find an example of it so i know which xml attributes to use, frame layout was helping me first but seems to give me some problems by now,

Thanks for your ideas in advance.

Comment: Did you look at LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, GridLayout?  Those, or combos of them, should do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with **Relative Layout**, its the best layout present which requires a minimum no. of lines as compared to other layouts and align views with respect to each other. If you want views to be divided in proportion then it is recommended to use **Linear Layout using weight concept.**

Comment: How to make the box layout then? Backgroundimage of????, i want multiple children of this "box"!

Comment: You can use a background image if you want else you can create your own shapes like this http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tricks-using-shape-for-theming/